# How to handle OAuth flow with Doorkeeper and Devise with PKCE flow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, devise, doorkeeper

Similar to [How to handle OAuth flow with Doorkeeper in API Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236940/how-to-handle-oauth-flow-with-doorkeeper-in-api-mode) but with PKCE flow. As it is not recommended to store client secrets on a front-end application, how can my front-end application (React) authenticate with my Rails api-only backend to authenticate with no sign-in page on the Rails side?

Is there a way to only allow third-party (non-trusted) applications to authenticate via OAuth with no user credentials interaction but allow trusted applications to pass user credentials in the body to authenticate all while using the PKCE grant flow?